# PHP friendly for Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, fopen

```
{php}
$from = 'EUR';
$to = 'RON';
$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1d1t1&s='.$from.$to.'=X';
$handle = fopen($url, 'r');

if ($handle) {
    $result = fgetcsv($handle);
    fclose($handle);
}

$suma = $result[0];
$totall = round($suma * $euroi, 2);

 {/php}
```

I tried to convert this php code to Smarty ("Friendly") PHP code, but i don't know what is wrong. I get this error:

> Smarty Error: Syntax error in template "/home2/hostro/public_html/templates/VoiceHost/viewinvoice.tpl" on line 131 "{php}" unknown tag "php"

Line 131 is `{php}`
Can you help me ? Thank you !
P.S: I have read documentation for Smarty , but no idea..
PPS: I searched stackoverflow for similar questions...

Comment: What smarty version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. Put
>   your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead.
>
> Note: As of Smarty 3.1 the {php} tags are only available from
>   SmartyBC.

Comment: So, that means i should use <?php and all i want ?

Comment: No, you should put your php in external scripts and assign your variables via smarty. If you want to use the depricated {php} then you need to use new SmartyBC and not new Smarty

Comment: Oh. Ok. I get it now ! Thank you ! I will be back with response if it works

Comment: Well, i don't know why, but instead `{php}` i used `<?php` and instead `{/php}` i used `?>` and it works without errors.

Comment: Yes, i use 3.1-DEV. It's for WHMCS' template